# Как вывести из функции значения списком

Tags: python, функции, list, список, return

Господа, помогите пожалуйста.
есть код такого типа:

```
def func:  
    тело функции  
    результат записался в list  
    return (list)
```

В другом участке кода вызываю func он выводит мне значения внутри list списком через запятую по типу ['arg1','arg2','arg3',...].
Можно ли как-то обратиться к функции так чтобы значения выводились бы столбиком? или может есть способ записать значения в list сразу столбиком? Или может можно в return указать какой то аргумент при котором list будет выдавать значения в столбец?

Comment: записать значения в list сразу столбиком - 

Comment: какова вообще цель этого странного процесса? Из вопроса ясно, что вы пытаетесь натянуть какой-то странный костыль вместо того, чтобы просто сделать по-нормальному.

Comment: судя по комментариям ТС к ответам, ТС нужно почитать документацию по телеграм API.

Comment: `print(*func(), sep='\n')` - если я правильно понял загадочные требования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предыдущий ответ при использовании его в функции будет выводить None в конце. Поэтому лучше использовать такой вариант:

```
return "\n".join(list)
```

Comment: все получилось, спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for el in lst:
    print(el)
```

Рекомендую читать учебники. Там очень много полезного.

Comment: Я внимательно читал вопрос - "чтобы значения выводились столбиком". А про "записать значения в list сразу столбиком" это такой бред, что даже непонятно, то ли плакать, то ли усмехнуться. Читайте учебники.

Comment: вы не внимательно читали мой вопрос. про перебор и принт я знаю. я в теле телеграм бота в качестве одного из ответов ссылаюсь на функцию, она в свою очередь ссылается на список, и в итоге список выводится как есть, в строку, мой вопрос заключается в том чтобы вывести результаты списка в столбец

Comment: В другом участке кода вызываю func он выводит мне значения внутри list списком через запятую по типу ['arg1','arg2','arg3',...].
Можно ли как-то обратиться к функции так чтобы значения выводились бы столбиком?

Comment: я вам и показал, как вывести элементы списка в столбец ("результаты списка" такая же ерунда, как "записать значения в список стобликом"). Сформулируйте внятно проблему и задачу со всеми условиями типа телеграма и т.д.